# express router, auth0 and vanilla javascript; how to provide auth after logged in to router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger, auth0

I've built a front end using vite with vanilla javascript. I've built a backend with node.js express routes. I've implemented swagger, and I can log in, log out, and I've secured post/put/delete routes by validating the request.oidc object, and it works great with swagger.

I've also implemented login/out to the same Auth0 service that secures the backend in the front end. But what isn't clear is how I attach the authentication to the post/put/delete routes in the front end.

It is clear that the routes are secured by testing via swagger, so that indicates that I don't have to implement anything more on the backend or in Auth0. I just can't find any documentation on how I provide the data to the backend that this user is authorized.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So by your sayings is that you use Auth0 to authenticate users and also OpenID. That means that you could use the session.token or look up the cookies for the JWT and then on subsequent requests you could include it in headers as Authorization. For reference : https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens#use-jwts